# PHP API main file

Tags: php, api

I have a question concerning an API that I am developing and I have just started asking myself the following question: As a rule, to reach the main file, you have to reach it in the following way api.domain.com/index.php/users/id/profile/... but many sites allow you to avoid calling the file index.php but put the "query" directly. My question is, what should I do in order not to enter the file name, since if I don't put index.php it goes missing because it sees the query as folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .htaccess file.
As an example, you may add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

And then use some sorte of routing (like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) or [Laravel routes](https://laravel.com/)) to redirect the user where you wanted. This way, you could call api.yousite.com/users/id/... and it'd go through the index.php anyway.

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264270/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-index-php) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess).

Comment: OP has not stated to be using Apache. This will not help people using PHP-FPM, for example.